I added LoadBar in my PySide6 GUI Program but it seems to be going on infinitely
So I added a loading bar for some tasks but it goes on infinitely long while without using it I can get the results in under 10 seconds.
So this is my loading bar class which I am using right now
class LoadingDialog(QDialog):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Working on your task")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Dialog | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 100)  # Fixed size dialog
    
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(30, 40, 240, 30)
        self.progress.setRange(0, 0)  # Indeterminate progress bar
    
        self.label = QLabel("Enumerating Please Wait...", self)
        self.label.setGeometry(110, 10, 80, 20)
    
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.progress)
    
    def showEvent(self, event):
        super().showEvent(event)
        self.progress.setRange(0, 0)  # Start indeterminate progress
    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super().closeEvent(event)
        self.progress.setRange(0, 0)  # Reset progress on close

and I am using it like this in my main GUI functions where I need it
        self.loading_dialog.exec()
    
        self.output_text.clear()
        self.output_text.append(f"Enumerating subdomains for {domain} using wordlist...\n")
    
        subdomains = self.subdomain_enum(domain, wordlist)
        if subdomains:
            self.display_subdomains("Wordlist", subdomains)
        else:
            self.output_text.append("No subdomains found.")
    
        self.loading_dialog.close()

Here is the functionality it takes 10 to 20 seconds as the wordlist i give it is only of 10 or 12 words.
def subdomain_enum(self, domain, wordlist):
        output = []
        subdomains = []
        with open(wordlist, 'r') as file:
            subdomains = file.read().splitlines()
        
        for subdomain in subdomains:
            try:
                full_domain = f"{subdomain}.{domain}"
                result = dns.resolver.resolve(full_domain, 'A')
                for ipval in result:
                    output_line = f'{full_domain} | {ipval.to_text()}'
                    output.append(output_line)
            except Exception as e:
                pass

        return output

This is for displaying the result where output box is a TextBrowser
def display_subdomains(self, source, subdomains):
        self.output_text.append(f"From {source}:")
        if subdomains:
            for subdomain in subdomains:
                self.output_text.append(f"  - {subdomain}")
        else:
            self.output_text.append(f"  No subdomains found from {source}.")

Now I haven't tried many solutions as I see no solutions regarding to this on web so need help. thank you.

exec() is blocking. Nothing after that line will ever happen until the dialog is closed. Besides: 1. Qt already provides QProgressDialog; 2. it's unclear what actually happens in subdomain_enum() and display_subdomains(), but if it's a computation heavy task, you won't accomplish anything with this approach, since they would be blocking the event loop preventing proper display of the dialog or update of the progress bar. Please clarify what actually happens there, possibly with a comprehensive [mre].

Can you provide me a correct snippet of how can i use it, subdomain enum just get the subdomain for specific domain provided and i can do that under 10 seconds without the loading bar and display subdomain just print that results in the TextBrowser

@musicamante here i have edited the question so you can see what I'm trying to do

See the documentation about QDialog.exec() (emphasis mine):

Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it.

This means that nothing after that line will ever be executed until the dialog is closed.
Consider the open() function instead:

Shows the dialog as a window modal dialog, returning immediately.

Now, even if using open() will allow the program to go on with the following instructions, the problem is that what happens after that is potentially blocking, meaning that the event loop will not be able to do anything, including properly updating the UI in the meantime.
You'll probably end up with an empty window that may look frozen, and that will close as soon as the other functions return.
In simple cases like this, where what happens in the blocking sections of the code is based on a relatively "fast" processing loop (each iteration would probably take less than a second), it is acceptable to force the event loop to process its events by calling QApplication.processEvents():
    def subdomain_enum(self, domain, wordlist):
        output = []
        subdomains = []
        with open(wordlist, 'r') as file:
            subdomains = file.read().splitlines()
        
        for subdomain in subdomains:
            QApplication.processEvents()
            ... # the rest of the code

Note, though, that this is just based on an educated guess and the hope that everything works fine: dns.resolver.resolve() may take much more time (probably due to network issues), with the result that it may still freeze the UI until a reply is received or an error is finally raised.
When dealing with I/O (network access included), it's common and highly suggested to move the logic in a separate thread.
Be aware that UI elements are not thread safe, so you must not try to access them from another thread. The only proper way to do so is by using signals, possibly by moving the "worker" logic to a QThread.
I suggest you to do some research on the matter, and eventually post a question with a related [mre] in case you are not able to make it work as expected.
